# Understanding type inference in Rust

Tags: rust, type-inference

This program does not compile: "type annotations needed".

```
fn main() {
    let sum = [0,1,2,3].iter().sum();
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

Even if I change the line to:

```
let sum = [0i32,1,2,3].iter().sum();
```

not even this:

```
let vec: [i32; 4] = [0,1,2,3];
let sum = vec.iter().sum();
```

Why the compiler can not do type inference?
Isn't it obvious that i want a **sum** with type **i32**?

Comment: tl;dr: no, it isn't obvious. Use `let sum: i32` to be explicit.